# identifying [] in an expression using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get this string to give me the exact matching result

session[username_or_email]

the expression

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="session[username_or_email]";
var patt1=/ID|un|name|login_username|userid|username|user|Email|uname|usr|log|email|mail|nick|CUST|account|wpName1|textbox|pw|session[username_or_email]/i;
document.write(str.match(patt1));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the result now is username

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the `[` with `\[` so it isn't treated as a special regex control character, but just a normal character to search for.

```
var str="session[username_or_email]";
var patt1=/ID|un|name|login_username|userid|username|user|Email|uname|usr|log|email|mail|nick|CUST|account|wpName1|textbox|pw|session\[username_or_email]/i;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CuWKV/

You don't actually have to escape the `]` because it is only an expected regex control character when a `[` has come before it though it does not harm to escape it also.

Comment: awesome ... you are a timesavour friend :D

Answer (score 1):

Please note the escaped \[ - I also moved the wanted string to the beginning since it contains username too - this may or may not be what you need, but you should consider it.

```
var str="session[username_or_email]";
var patt1=/session\[username_or_email\]|ID|un|name|login_username|userid|username|user|Email|uname|usr|log|email|mail|nick|CUST|account|wpName1|textbox|pw/i;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```